# How do I make a command in a batch file not prompt to front?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have a bat file contains the following commands.

```
start /WAIT /d "C:\Program Files\7-Zip" 7z.exe u -ms=off "D:\7zbackup\android.7z" "C:\xampp\htdocs\android"
start /WAIT /d "C:\Program Files\7-Zip" 7z.exe u -ms=off "D:\7zbackup\aspnet.7z" "C:\xampp\htdocs\aspnet"
start /WAIT /d "C:\Program Files\7-Zip" 7z.exe u -ms=off "D:\7zbackup\bitbucket.7z" "C:\xampp\htdocs\bitbucket"
start /WAIT /d "C:\Program Files\7-Zip" 7z.exe u -ms=off "D:\7zbackup\bitbucket_sourcetree.7z" "C:\xampp\htdocs\bitbucket_sourcetree"
```

It will prompt a cmd window to the front for each line of the command. How do I make it not prompt and run minimized or run in the background?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`start`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) with parameter '/B':

```
start /B /WAIT /d "C:\Program Files\7-Zip" 7z.exe u -ms=off "D:\7zbackup\android.7z" "C:\xampp\htdocs\android"
```

`/b`: Starts an application without opening a new command prompt window. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> handling is ignored unless the application enables <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> processing. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd> to interrupt the application. (*[Start](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491005.aspx)* (TechNet).)

Answer (score 13):

It is your use of `start` which causes the new window to appear.

`7z` is 7-Zip's command-line program, so it can be called directly:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" u ...
```

This way everything stays within the original window.

Comment: not working, can't detect the command line option

Comment: @hkguie - I don't understand your response "can't detect the command line option": you're passing exactly the same parameter string as you used with the `start` command, so command line options should not be a problem, unless you mis-typed.